# Building the cordova.jar file

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

i am trying to build a cordova.jar file. i am using phonegap 2.9.1. i have done everything i should. i have set up the JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME and have even set up their respective locations in the PATH. I have even included the platform-tools and tools of my android sdk too in the PATH. i have followed every tutorials i saw but i have the same issues. when i run  android update project -p . -t android-19 from the phonegap/lib/android/framework directory, what i get is 'android' is not an internal command. i change it to android update project -p . -t android-17, same thing. I saw another tutorial that told me to go to the cordova-android directory of the cordova zip file i have downloaded (cordova 3.4.0) which told me to navigate to its framework directory and run 'ant jar'. I did it and to my surprise what i got was 'ant' is not an internal command.

i am so lost here and need some clarification. if there is anywhere i can even download the cordova2.9.1.jar file, please i wouldn't mind

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it. i simply re-entered the values of ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and PATH. I ran the  ant command and it worked like a charm but i had to download cordova-android master 3.4.1 from github and ran the whole comands to build the jar file and it did